# Caffe - Feedforward image using trained caffemodel from shell

Tags: shell, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

Suppose I have a trained caffe model (`.caffemodel` weights file and `.prototxt` file with the description of the net) and an image that I want to classify using this net (a simple feed-forward, then get the output values of the last layer), assume the image has the correct dimensions for the first layer of the net.

I've seen tutorials doing this with Matlab or Python.

Is there a way of doing it with Caffe itself from shell? (without using bindings in another language)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the caffe.bin executable in build/tools/ folder running in `test` mode. What more option do you expect than the result of running this executable?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this the following way:

```
./build/tools/extract_features.bin
models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel
examples/_temp/imagenet_val.prototxt fc7 examples/_temp/features 10 leveldb
```

Instead of "fc7" you can specify the name or even multiple names of the layers you want the output from. Also checkout these links for more details: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/tools/extract_features.cpp#L36-L45,
http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/feature_extraction.html

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`$CAFFE_ROOT/python/classify.py`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/classify.py) from shell to classify an image:

```
~$ python $CAFFE_ROOT/python/classify.py \
      --model_def /path/to/deploy.prototxt \
      --pretrained_model /path/to/weights.caffemodel \
      --gpu \
      /path/to/image.jpg /path/to/output
```

There are some more optional parameters for this python script, you might need to set some of them.